# Card Deck Carousel with Arrow Control

Tags: html, css, web, pure-css

I want to create a Card Carousel with Pure CSS

https://www.codeply.com/go/WEbiqQvGhy

Is there any way to do it....

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't
you have to use `Javascript`

there is a document of how to create a carousel with `css` and `Javascript`:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp